# Sublime Text 2 IDE for Play 1.2.5

Tags: java, playframework, sublimetext2, playframework-1.x

I installed the Play 2 package for Sublime Text 2.

Is it possible to use the same for an older version of Play framework i.e. 1.2.5 ?

I tried creating a project in the older play version and open the folder in Sublime Text IDE. The compilation errors in index.xml file are not getting detected by the IDE, hence concerned whether it works or not.

Not sure if someone have tried using the IDE for older Play version.

Please let me know about this.

If it works then the problem is with my installaton.

**edit**

Also, let me know if SUblime Text 2 wont work with Play framework 1.2.5 then is there some older version of Sublime Text available in market which might work with Play Framework 1.2.5 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 is not an IDE so you won't get the errors of compilations in it, it's just a text editor. The package for play 2 just brings syntax coloration to the scala templates and some code snippets.

If you really want to use an IDE, you should try Eclipse and the play plugin: https://github.com/playframework/playclipse

Comment: In Eclipse IDE, I am not able to open the file `main.html`. When tried, got the error: `Character encoding is not supported...`Other html files are opening except `main.html`. Please let me know how to open the `main.html` file in Eclipse then? Thanks.